# Delete Children Automatically

Tags: python, scripting, parent, operator, select

Is there a way to *automatically* delete children when the parent is deleted? By automatically I mean that you don't do any selection (or other action) of the children prior to selecting and deleting the parent.

I can make a method that select and delete the children. But I'm not sure how to call this prior to the `bpy.ops.object.delete()` operator. Maybe some custom property of the objects with some clever update? Or maybe a handle?

EDIT:
I tried to override the delete operator like this:

```
class MYOP_OT_delete_family(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "object.delete"
    bl_label = "Delete parent, children and sibling"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'} # Must have REGISTER!   

    def execute(self, context):
        
        top_object = context.object
        
        if top_object.parent is not None:
            top_object = top_object.parent
        
        top_object.select_set(True)
        for child in top_object.children:
            child.select_set(True)

        bpy.ops.object.delete() # BUT THIS IS NOW OVERRIDDEN!!!
            
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

This breaks Blender when I delete something. This is not surprising, since I both rely on and override the bpy.ops.delete operator. I suppose that I can make this as a new operator (bpy.ops.delete_family as the class name) and then keymap to this operator. But I would prefer not to have to do these manual setup things and truely override the default delete operator.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101520/how-can-i-disable-edit-source-at-my-ui

Comment: *Or* just override the context: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27235 ?

Comment: Always obtuse. Script shows  how to select  parent and siblings recursively (calls itself)  and endlessly select and select...never-bloody-endingly...  Suggest  Look for an  API method to remove objects.  Look for a way to select hierarchy   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145620/looping-over-hierarchies-of-objects-with-python

Comment: @batFINGER. That was kinda rude. I'm trying as good as I can to clarify what I want to do, which is difficult since I don't understand the entire API. But your idea for overriding the delete operator is really good and something I haven't seen any other place where people asked about this topic. It actually works pretty well now.